# gwt file upload code

Tags: gwt, file-upload

I want to upload file in my application and want to set path where the files should be saved after uploading in my local system.I am using the following code but on the submit button getting no response while clicking.Please tell me the code which works fine for the file upload in gwt.
[code]

```
public class FormPanelExample implements EntryPoint {

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a FormPanel and point it at a service.
    final FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
    form.setAction("/myFormHandler");

    // Because we're going to add a FileUpload widget, we'll need to set the
    // form to use the POST method, and multipart MIME encoding.
    form.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

    // Create a panel to hold all of the form widgets.
    VerticalPanel panel = new VerticalPanel();
    form.setWidget(panel);

    // Create a TextBox, giving it a name so that it will be submitted.
    final TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.setName("textBoxFormElement");
    panel.add(tb);

    // Create a ListBox, giving it a name and some values to be associated with
    // its options.
    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    lb.setName("listBoxFormElement");
    lb.addItem("foo", "fooValue");
    lb.addItem("bar", "barValue");
    lb.addItem("baz", "bazValue");
    panel.add(lb);

    // Create a FileUpload widget.
    FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
    upload.setName("uploadFormElement");
    panel.add(upload);

    // Add a 'submit' button.
    panel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickListener() {
      public void onClick(Widget sender) {
        form.submit();
      }
    }));

    // Add an event handler to the form.
    form.addFormHandler(new FormHandler() {
      public void onSubmit(FormSubmitEvent event) {
        // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can take
        // this opportunity to perform validation.
        if (tb.getText().length() == 0) {
          Window.alert("The text box must not be empty");
          event.setCancelled(true);
        }
      }

      public void onSubmitComplete(FormSubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
        // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
        // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
        // further explanation).
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(form);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Amandeep

Comment: Does the file get uploaded? I had some issues with fileupload using GWT myself, and the uploading worked fine, but the callback wasn't triggered. I'll try to find what I did to fix it. (I do remember that I ended up writing my own service handle it in the backend, though)

Comment: No the file does not uploaded I am not calling the code on the server side it is a client side java program so there is no problem of calling the code. I dont know how I can set the location of the file uploaded.

Comment: @stein I guess the reason callback didn't trigger is: you might haven't set the `formPanel.errorReader`. If your code is the same as amandeep's one.

Answer (score 0):

Now, I remember.. There's a bug in the FormPanel code that causes `form.submit()` not to work, when the type of the form is changed from the default (don't know if it's fixed yet in any release of GWT). If you create a "native" submit button like this:

```
HTML nativeSubmitButton new HTML("<input class='gwt-Button' type='submit' value='" + buttonText + "' />")
```

It will submit the form.

The disadvantage is that you cannot use any Button methods on this object, since it's a simple HTML wrapper. So disabling the button on submit (to avoid accidental double submit, and to give feedback that the form is actually submitting) won't work .

I've created a utility class for this purpose myself called DisableableSubmitButton that is essentially a FlowPanel with one HTML button like the above, and one gwt Button that is disabled, and some logic to toggle each of them visible. Since it cannot modify the actual enabled status of the HTML button all submit handlers must ask this class if it's "enabled" or not and cancel the event if it is. If you're interested in this implementation, i could share it with you (I don't want to flood stackoverflow with code unless you are interested).

Comment: Can you provide me a sample working code for uploading the file using gwt?

Comment: My code is quite large, and it's not (unfortunately) opensource, but I may share some small clever snippets of mine if you'd like such as the pseudo button class. -- But your sample code does not look that different from mine. Did you try to use the "HTML-button" trick? Try using firebug to see if the form is actually submitted etc.

Comment: GWT is kind of slow to build so I won't bother trying to compile your code to test it... ;)