# Upload file using gwt FileUpload widget without submit button

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gwt file upload code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6410004/gwt-file-upload-code)

I want to use FileUpload in gwt without having a submit button next to this widget. For example: I press browse button to browse for the file I intend to upload. After I find the file and select it, I press the Open button. Now, is it possible to use this Open button to send the file to server instead of having another submit button.

Comment: Did u get this working? I also need to do the same.can u pls share if u have done.

Answer (score 1):

Register a `ChangeHandler` on the `FileUpload` that `submit()`s the `FormPanel`.